# Zip 2 different Mono in Spring Webfux

Tags: java, spring-webflux, reactor-netty

I have the below function

```
public Mono<CarAndShip> getCarAndShip(Long id) {
    Mono<Car> carMono = carService.getCar(id).subscribeOn(Schedulers.elastic());
    Mono<Ship> shipMono = shipService.getShip(id).subscribeOn(Schedulers.elastic());

    return Mono.zip(carMono, shipMono)
        .flatMap(zipMono -> {
            return new CarAndShip(zipMono.getT1(), zipMono.getT2());
        });
```

IntelliJ complains at the return statement that:

```
Required type: Mono <CarAndShip> 
Provided: Mono <Object> no
instance(s) of type variable(s) R exist so that CarAndShip conforms to Mono<? extends R>
```

How do I type cast to the required `CarAndShip` return type?

Comment: What does your `CarAndShip` class look like? Why not just return `Mono<Tuple2<Car, Ship>>`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Required type: Mono   Provided: Mono  no
> instance(s) of type variable(s) R exist so that CarAndShip conforms to
> Mono<? extends R>

As the exception says: you're not providing a Mono.

So either use `map` instead of `flatMap`:

```
return Mono.zip(carMono, shipMono)
    .map(zipMono -> new CarAndShip(zipMono.getT1(), zipMono.getT2()));
```

or provide a Mono (probably not the best way here):

```
return Mono.zip(carMono, shipMono)
    .flatMap(zipMono -> Mono.just(new CarAndShip(zipMono.getT1(), zipMono.getT2())));
```

Answer (score 2):

In this example you should be using `map()` instead of `flatMap()` as you are not returning a `Mono`.